# Image Handler returning same image after multiple calls in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, caching, handler

Im trying to create an image handler for my website, the basic resizing, rotating and cropping works, and displays fine in the website however I tried to add caching to the handler by saving the file in `/chached/filename.png` but for some reason after I've added caching, the image handler is returning the wrong image. For example I have a project listing page where  the resized project images are displayed in a tabular view, however the first 4 projects display as having the same image and then the next 4 a different image but all the same, etc etc.

I have a feeling it's due to the `response.outputstream` but I'm not sure because it seems like it's not getting enough time to complete the first image before the next one is called.

Just in case, the full code is available here: http://pastebin.com/BNyDfqPy

My process request method is as follows:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    // Settings and locations
    appPath = HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath;
    location = context.Request.QueryString["image"];
    cacheLocation = Path.GetDirectoryName(appPath + location) + "/Cached/";

    // Input/Output
    Bitmap bitOutput;
    Bitmap bitInput = GetImage(context);

    if (cacheAvailable)
    {
        bitOutput = bitInput;
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            Boolean crop = false;

            if (context.Request["type"] == "crop")
            {
                crop = true;
            }

            bitInput = RotateFlipImage(context, bitInput);

            if (hasSetSize)
            {
                Int32 x = String.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Request["x"]) ? 0 : Int32.Parse(context.Request["x"]);
                Int32 y = String.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Request["y"]) ? 0 : Int32.Parse(context.Request["y"]);

                bitOutput = ResizeImage(bitInput, _width, _height, crop, x, y);

                bitOutput.Save(cacheLocation + cacheKey + ".png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            bitOutput = bitInput;
        }
    }


    context.Response.Clear();
    context.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
    context.Response.ContentType = "image/png";

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        bitOutput.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        ms.WriteTo(context.Response.OutputStream);
    }
    //bitOutput.Save(context.Response.OutputStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

    bitOutput.Dispose();
    bitInput.Dispose();
    context.Response.Flush();

    return;        
}
```

And I get the image using this:

```
public Bitmap GetImage(HttpContext context)
{
    // Get location
    Bitmap bitOutput = null;

    try
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(location))
        {
            Image image = Image.FromFile(appPath + location);
            bitOutput = new Bitmap(image);
            hasSetSize = SetHeightWidth(context, bitOutput);

            if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(cacheLocation))
            {
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(cacheLocation);
            }

            // Generate cache key
            cacheKey = "imagehandler_" + _width + "x" + _height + "_" + context.Request["RotateFlip"] + context.Request["type"];

            if (File.Exists(cacheLocation + cacheKey + ".png"))
            {
                image = Image.FromFile(cacheLocation + cacheKey + ".png");
                bitOutput = new Bitmap(image);
                cacheAvailable = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Can't load original or save to cache, check directory permissions!");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        Image image = Image.FromFile(appPath + noImageUrl);
        bitOutput = new Bitmap(image);
    }

    return bitOutput;
}
```

I also have `isReusable` set as following:

```
public bool IsReusable
{
    get
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The output looks like the image below, every project has a different image set but they either show the same image as the previous/next image, it's own image (which is what I want) or the placeholder image:

[image: List of projects that are supposed to have different images]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see the code you have probably use static variable for the `cacheAvailable` and after is set to true is not get back to false for the next call.

So check when you make the `cacheAvailable` false as default for every request.

Comment: I've removed cacheAvailable from being static and placed it as a variable inside getImage(), still the same output, any ideas?

Comment: @LukeAlderton Can you please give the full page code ? Or simple make  cacheAvailable=false at the call of the handler

Comment: @LukeAlderton as I see it fast, I say you to remove all 4 static ! and try it. My prediction for the `cacheAvailable` was correct :)

Comment: Ah, that did it, I had to clear out the cache and then reload the page and it's all working now, thank you a lot, you know how it is when you've been coding for hours and the simplest things get you stuck! ;)

Answer (score 0):

First, unless you really want your handler to be able to use the same instance over and over, have `IsReusable` return false.

If you don't want to do that, remove the `cacheAvailable` class level variable, change this:

```
// Input/Output
Bitmap bitOutput;
Bitmap bitInput = GetImage(context);
```

To this:

```
// Input/Output
Bitmap bitOutput;
bool cacheAvailable;
Bitmap bitInput = GetImage(context, out cacheAvailable);
```

And modify `GetImage` to look like this

```
public Bitmap GetImage(HttpContext context, out bool cacheAvailable)
{
    // Get location
    Bitmap bitOutput = null;
    cacheAvailable = false;

    try
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(location))
        {
            Image image = Image.FromFile(appPath + location);
            bitOutput = new Bitmap(image);
            hasSetSize = SetHeightWidth(context, bitOutput);

            if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(cacheLocation))
            {
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(cacheLocation);
            }

            // Generate cache key
            cacheKey = "imagehandler_" + _width + "x" + _height + "_" + context.Request["RotateFlip"] + context.Request["type"];

            if (File.Exists(cacheLocation + cacheKey + ".png"))
            {
                image = Image.FromFile(cacheLocation + cacheKey + ".png");
                bitOutput = new Bitmap(image);
                cacheAvailable = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Can't load original or save to cache, check directory permissions!");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        Image image = Image.FromFile(appPath + noImageUrl);
        bitOutput = new Bitmap(image);
    }

    return bitOutput;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help but the isResuable is set to return false as far as I know, I've updated my code snippets to include this, however I followed your suggested updates to the code and it's still giving me the same output. Any ideas?